# Create events in weekly timeseries

Tags: r, date, time-series

I want to create a table with two columns. The first one represents the working weeks, named time_axis in my exemple below.
The second column, is also a sequence of Dates which represents particular events in a year, called bank_holidays. Each of the date get a one value to signalise its presence.
What I need, is to create a table where the first columns time axis remains unchanged and the second column will be a vector of ones and zeros. Zeros anywhere outside the weeks which contain the events in bank_holiday and with ones for the weeks which includes those dates in bank_holiday occurs. Every week starts with the date in time_axis

```
library(xts)
time_axis <- seq(as.Date("2017-01-21"), length = 10, by = "weeks")
bank_holidays <- as.Date(c("2017-02-01", "2017-02-13", "2017-02-18", "2018-03-18"))
bank_holidays <- as.xts(rep(1,4), order.by = bank_holidays)
```

The desired outcome:

```
 df <- data.frame ( time_axis =  c("2017-01-20", "2017-01-27", "2017-02-03", "2017-02-10", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-24", "2017-03-03", "2017-03-10", "2017-03-17", "2017-03-24"), bank_holidays = c(0, 1, 0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0))
 df
```

Any idee on how to make it?
Thank you.

Something which needs to bear in mind and is not obviously from the data: the weeks on time_axis start on Saturday. Therefore, 2017-01-21 is not the end of the 3rd week (as if it would be in case the week starts on Monday) but it is already the 4th week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `strftime`, `"%V"` gives the ISO 8601 week numbers where you may match on.

```
res <- data.frame(time_axis, 
                  bank_holidays =+(strftime(time_axis, "%V") %in%
                                     strftime(index(bank_holidays), "%V")))
res
#     time_axis bank_holidays
# 1  2017-01-20             0
# 2  2017-01-27             0
# 3  2017-02-03             1
# 4  2017-02-10             0
# 5  2017-02-17             1
# 6  2017-02-24             0
# 7  2017-03-03             0
# 8  2017-03-10             0
# 9  2017-03-17             1
# 10 2017-03-24             0
```

#### Edit

To use the custom working weeks whose starts are defined in *time_axis* variable, the simplest thing would probably be to compare if *bank_holidays* are greater or equal than that. Then counting the `TRUE`s with `colSums` gives the index where to set to 1.

```
res <- data.frame(time_axis, bank_holidays=0)  ## init. column with `0`
res$bank_holidays[colSums(sapply(index(bank_holidays), `>=`, time_axis))] <- 1  ## set matches to 1
res
#     time_axis bank_holidays
# 1  2017-01-21             0
# 2  2017-01-28             1
# 3  2017-02-04             0
# 4  2017-02-11             1
# 5  2017-02-18             1
# 6  2017-02-25             0
# 7  2017-03-04             0
# 8  2017-03-11             0
# 9  2017-03-18             1
# 10 2017-03-25             0
```

Comment: Thank you for you replay. The solution you gave it works provided that the week starts on Mondays. In my case, the week starts on Saturday after. Therefore, 2017-01-21 will be already the 4th working week instead of the third. I have corrected the question to reflect this. Any clue on how to change this?

Comment: @gogo88 I see, came up with another solution, see Edit please.

Comment: This solution does exactly what I need . thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, a little bit longer than the previous answer but you can see what's happening here

I need the start date and end date so I can fill the rest of the dates in between so I'm selecting 11 weeks instead of 10 in your example. And also I can match the vector for bank holidays instead of xts object

```
library(xts)
library(tidyverse)

time_axis <- seq(as.Date("2017-01-20"), length = 11, by = "weeks") 
bank_holidays <- as.Date(c("2017-02-01", "2017-02-13", "2017-02-18", "2018-03-18")) # I'll work with the vector 
#bank_holidays <- as.xts(rep(1,4), order.by = bank_holidays)


df <- tibble() # I'm creating an empty tibble
for(i in 1:(length(time_axis)-1))  { # running a for loop for 10 weeks 
  
  df <- seq(as.Date(time_axis[i]), as.Date(time_axis[i+1]), "days") %>% # filling the dates between the two dates
    enframe(name = NULL) %>% #converting it into a data frame (tibble)
    mutate(week = as.Date(time_axis[i])) %>% # creating a new column indicating which week the given date belong to
    bind_rows(df) # binding the rows to previous dataframe
}
```

Now I'm taking the df and checking the given holidays matching with our generated dates or not. if present 1 or it will be 0.
Then I'm group_by based on week column which is our given weeks above and summarising to find the sum

```
df %>% 
  mutate(bank_holidays_presence = if_else(value %in% bank_holidays, 1, 0)) %>% 
  group_by(week) %>% 
  summarise(sum = bank_holidays_presence %>% sum())

# A tibble: 10 x 2
#  week         sum
#   <date>     <dbl>
# 1 2017-01-20     0
# 2 2017-01-27     1
# 3 2017-02-03     0
# 4 2017-02-10     1
# 5 2017-02-17     1
# 6 2017-02-24     0
# 7 2017-03-03     0
# 8 2017-03-10     0
# 9 2017-03-17     0
#10 2017-03-24     0
```

The advantage of this method is that even if you have more than one holiday for a particular week it'll give the count rather than mere presence or absence